# Unable to insert record after creating a trigger for insert

Tags: sql-server

I have created a new trigger using this SQL statement in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio

```
CREATE trigger [OTCS].[EventLogTrigger] 
ON [OT_ELIB105_ContentServer].[OTCS].[DAuditNew]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO [ByDOT].[dbo].[OtcsEventLog]
       ([EventID]
       ,[AuditID]
       ,[AuditStr]
       ,[AuditDate]
       ,[DataID]
       ,[SubType]
       ,[UserID]
       ,[PerformerID]
       ,[ValueKey]
       ,[ApplicationID]
       ,[LanguageCode])
   SELECT  
       [EventID]
   ,[AuditID]
       ,[AuditStr]
       ,[AuditDate]
       ,[DataID]
       ,[SubType]
       ,[UserID]
       ,[PerformerID]
       ,[ValueKey]
       ,[ApplicationID]
       ,[LanguageCode] FROM inserted
END
GO
```

After creating the above trigger the web application is not able to insert a record into the `DAuditNew` table.

The above two tables belong to two different DB's.

The web application is OpenText Content Server.

Comment: Are you having permission issues from one database to the other? What's the error message?

Comment: Having triggers access anything outside of their own database is almost always asking for trouble. Can you not introduce some form of intermediate storage (such as service broker queues) that deal with the niceties of getting data from one DB to the other even in the face of e.g. one DB being temporarily unavailable.

Comment: The web application is OpenText Content Server and I cannot create a new table in that DB. The error is "Error Inserting auditing record into Database". I already did this in test server, and now when I try it in production it's not working. But when I disable the trigger the application works fine.

Answer (score 0):

A Better solution would be to have the Audit tables locally, then you don't have to worry about one database being offline or down. You can always create cross database views if you need to access the Audit data from a different database.

Comment: Hey! How do i check if there is any permission issues?